# How to properly pass headers when using SWR?

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth, twitch-api, swr

I have decided to attempt to move majority of my API function to SWR as it simply allows me to do so much more!

#### Problem

However, I am having a huge issue where I cannot figure out how to properly pass headers into SWR. I've looked at the docs and more and yet nothing seems to do the trick. I am using Twitch API, Next.js and NextAuth for handling tokens, sessions, etc. I have left my GitHub repo below along with the code I am currently trying to use.

#### Note:

I console log the error return if an error occurs yet, when I access the page `/dash` it says `failed to load` yet there is no console log of an error?

#### [Github Repo](https://github.com/MatWebsites/twitchdash)

```js
import axios from "axios";
import Link from "next/link";
import {
  VStack,
  Heading,
  Divider,
  Text,
  Box,
  Badge,
  Center,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react"
import useSWR from 'swr'

const fetcher = (url) => {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession()
  axios
    .get(url, { 
        headers: { 
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${session.accessToken}`,
          'Client-Id': `${process.env.TWITCH_CLIENT_ID}`
        }})
    .then((res) => res.data);
}
     
function Dash () {
  const { data, error } = useSWR(`https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams/key?broadcaster_id=630124067`,fetcher)
  
  if (error) return (
    console.log(error),
    <div>Failed to load</div>
  )
  if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>

  return (
    <VStack>
      <Text>{data.user_name}</Text>
    </VStack>
  )
}

export default Dash
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You can use an array as the `key` parameter in `useSWR` to pass [multiple arguments](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/arguments#multiple-arguments) to the `fetcher` function.

---

First, `useSession` is a React hook, and should only be called at the top level of a React component/another hook. This avoids breaking the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

Second, you should move the `useSession` call to the `Dash` component. You can then call the `fetcher` conditionally (see [Conditional Fetching](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/conditional-fetching)) when the `session` exists, and pass the `accessToken` to the fetcher method using an array as the `key` parameter.

```js
function Dash() {
    const { data: session } = useSession()

    const { data, error } = useSWR(
        session ? ['https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams/key?broadcaster_id=630124067', session.accessToken] : null, 
        fetcher
    )
  
    // Remaining code
}
```

Lastly, your `fetcher` function will have to be modified slightly to accept the `accessToken` parameter. Note that you also need a `return` statement on the `axios` call for it to return the data properly.

```js
const fetcher = (url, accessToken) => {
    return axios
        .get(url, { 
            headers: { 
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                'Client-Id': `${process.env.TWITCH_CLIENT_ID}`
            }
        })
        .then((res) => res.data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edits and the reply, the Bearer token successfully sends to authenticate the api everything works great. I appreciate the amount of help you have given me on here. Will recommend others to this post if there having the same issue